# Deploy edited npm package

Tags: angular, azure, npm, node-modules

I have installed npm package **`ngx-cookie-service`**

I have also changed code in `node_module > ngx-cookie-service` folder this works fine on local host but when I deployed my angular app to azure, these changes not working.

How to make it work on server?

Comment: Did you try install the package in Kudu and change the code as you did in your local.

Comment: How are you building/deploying your application? If you are building it locally using `ng build`, then the built app will respect your local changes to node_modules. If you are building something serverside, it's likely doing an npm/yarn install before building it - which won't have your local changes.

Your best bet is to either subsume the logic in to your actual application, or if this is **really** not an option, fork the npm package and re-publish your own.

Answer (score 0):

Since when your app works fine on local, there are two ways to make it work on Azure WebApp.

1. Just directly upload all files and directories of your project to Azure and configure the `web.config` file to make it work as same as on local. You can refer to the offical documents [`Create a Node.js web app in Azure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs) and [`Deploy your app to Azure App Service with a ZIP or WAR file`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip) to create a zip file of your project, or directly upload all to the `wwwroot` path of Kudo Console, which must includes `node_module` directory and even excludes `package.json` to avoid automatically update your changes for `ngx-cookie-service`, then to configure `web.config` like [`Best practices and troubleshooting guide for node applications on Azure App Service Windows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-nodejs-best-practices-and-troubleshoot-guide) and [`Using a custom web.config for Node apps`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps) said. It's the simplest way manually.
2. As @hevans900 said, you can create a new NPM package for your changed `ngx-cookie-service` to publish to public hub, and reference it in your project to rebuild and redeploy.